# Reading Button Names from a File

Tags: java, swing, file, jbutton

I have 3 buttons and I need to set their names by reading from a file. Here's what I have so far:

```
BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("ButtonNames.txt"));       
    String buttonName = "";
    int startLine = 1;
    int endLine = 3;
    for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++)
    {
        buttonName = inputFile.readLine();
    }
    Button1 = new JButton(buttonName);
    buttonPanel.add(Button1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

This will only set the button name to the last line in the file. How do I set button1's name to the first line, button2's to the second line, etc. I'm thinking you need to use an array, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that code at the bottom ***inside*** of the for loop.

```
for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++)
{
    buttonName = inputFile.readLine();
    Button1 = new JButton(buttonName);
    buttonPanel.add(Button1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
}
```

Comment: It still displays the last line of text in the file. I think the loop displays the button name for the first line, then it starts over and display the second line, and then it displays the third line.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[3];
for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++)
{
    String buttonName = inputFile.readLine();
    buttons[i-1] = new JButton(buttonName);
    buttonPanel.add(buttons[i-1], BorderLayout.LINE_START);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works well:

```
public Main() {
    Panel p = new Panel();
    String[] names = Names("res/ButtonNames.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        p.add(new Button(names[i]));
    }
    frame.add(p);
}

private String[] Names(String filepath) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filepath)));
        String[] split = br.readLine().split(",");
        br.close();
        return split;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```